# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 $

Tags: android, kotlin

Having a bit of trouble with getting my app to talk to the API (keeps throwing the above error when app is launched).

I'm using `retrofit2` and `okhttp3`, and using the `retrofit2 GsonConverterFactory`.

**Sample API**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "AwkwardHelplessSalamanderSwiftRage",
      "url": "https://clips.twitch.tv/AwkwardHelplessSalamanderSwiftRage",
      "embed_url": "https://clips.twitch.tv/embed?clip=AwkwardHelplessSalamanderSwiftRage",
      "broadcaster_id": "67955580",
      "broadcaster_name": "ChewieMelodies",
      "creator_id": "53834192",
      "creator_name": "BlackNova03",
      "video_id": "205586603",
      "game_id": "488191",
      "language": "en",
      "title": "babymetal",
      "view_count": 10,
      "created_at": "2017-11-30T22:34:18Z",
      "thumbnail_url": "https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/157589949-preview-480x272.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
 private fun loadData() {
    val service  = TwitchServiceBuilder.buildService(TwitchService::class.java)
    val requestCall = service.getClips()

    requestCall.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Clip>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Clip>>,
                                response: Response<List<Clip>>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity,2)
                recyclerView.adapter = ClipAdapter(response.body()!!)

            }else{
                //output alert
                AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                    .setTitle("API error")
                    .setMessage("Response, but something went wrong ${response.message()}")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ -> }
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show()
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Clip>>, t: Throwable) {
            //process failure
            AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                .setTitle("API error")
                .setMessage("No response, and something went wrong $t")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ -> }
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show()

        }
    })
}
```

**TwitchService.kt**

```
interface TwitchService
{
    @GET("clips?broadcaster_id=74298145)")

    fun getClips(): Call<List<Clip>>
}
```

**TwitchServiceBuilder.kt**

```
object TwitchServiceBuilder
{
    private const val URL ="https://api.twitch.tv/helix/"

    var client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request: Request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer *****")
                .addHeader("Client-ID", "*****")
                .build()

            return@addInterceptor chain.proceed(request)
        }
        .build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()

    fun <T> buildService (serviceType :Class<T>):T{
        return retrofit.create(serviceType)
    }
}
```

**ClipAdapter.kt**

```
class ClipAdapter(private val clips: List<Clip>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ClipAdapter.ViewHolder>()
{
    override fun getItemCount(): Int
    {
        return clips.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder
    {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.clip_layout, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)
    {
        val theClip = clips.get(position)
        Picasso.get().load(theClip.thumbnails.medium).into(holder.clipImage)
        holder.clipTitle.text = theClip.title
        ("Channel: " + theClip.broadcaster.displayName).also { holder.clipChannel.text = it }
        ("Game: " + theClip.game).also { holder.clipGame.text = it }
        ("Views: " + theClip.views.toString()).also { holder.clipViews.text = it }
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
    {
        val clipImage = view.imgClip
        val clipTitle = view.txtTitle
        val clipChannel = view.txtChannel
        val clipGame = view.txtChannel
        val clipViews = view.txtChannel
    }
}
```

I've tried using a SearchResponse data class to retrieve the data instead (but this just causes the app to crash), and followed a lot of suggested answers on here to no avail.

**TwitchClipSearchResponse.kt**

```
data class TwitchClipSearchResponse(
    val data: List<Clip>
)
```

Knowing me it's probably a silly error somewhere (I'm fairly new to this) so appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created `TwitchClipSearchResponse`, but using `List<Clip>` as return type in `TwitchService`.

```
interface TwitchService
{
    @GET("clips?broadcaster_id=74298145)")

    fun getClips(): Call<TwitchClipSearchResponse>
}
```

Comment: That was an error on my part - I have updated it to Call<TwitchClipSearchResponse> and still get the "App has stopped" crash error.

Comment: If the reason for crash is different this time, can you post that ?

Comment: So I've checked the logs, and it the reason for the crash was because `recyclerView must not be null`. The whole app is loaded within 4 fragments, and the recycler view is within the second fragment not the first. I temporarily added the recyclerview to the first fragment, and the app loads but then gives a `RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` error instead.

Answer (score 0):

fix in your API interface TwitchService

```
    @GET("clips?broadcaster_id=74298145)")
    fun getClips(): Call<TwitchClipSearchResponse>
```

Comment: That was an error on my part - I have updated it to Call<TwitchClipSearchResponse> and still get the "App has stopped" crash error.

Comment: share you stacktrace